# Django model with properties that come from an external API

Tags: python, django, class, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to have properties on a model that come from an external API. I also want to leave those properties blank when the ORM loads an instance of the model so that queries within the ORM aren't making API requests unless explicitly asked. It'd be nice if I could call a function on the model to retrieve those external properties, maybe something like `.with_external()`. How could I achieve this? Here's what I'm starting with:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def external_id(self):
        external_id = requests.get({API_URL})
        return external_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible if did a little modification?
Add `_fetch_external = False` and will set it as **False** inside the `Project` class. and edit the `external_id` to be like that:

```
@property
def external_id(self):
    if self._fetch_external:
        external_id = requests.get(API_URL)
        return external_id
    return None
```

From what I understood from your question I would do that because the new `external_id` prop will make the API request and returns the external ID. If the flag is False, it returns None.
Now you can add:

```
@classmethod
def with_external(cls):
    instance = cls()
    instance._fetch_external = True
    return instance
```

with this method, you will create a new instance of the `Project` class with the `_fetch_external` flag set to **True**. This allows you to retrieve external properties only when requested.